# MKMapView Placing a pin on a country using its name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mkmapview

I have an array of country names and wish to place them on a MKMapView as Placemarks. So for example if France is in the countryName array I would like a pin placed on the center of France.

Is there a way of doing this without having the lat/long stored for each country?

I would like to make this work offline and only require the map in its most basic and fully zoomed out image of the world.

I believe MKMapView holds some basic geo information so is the above possible without the use of GLGeocoder and a internet connection?

Comment: The built-in MKMapView doesn't work offline - a quick fix would be to add an map overlay with a basic world map when there is no internet connection.

Comment: @NielsCastle If I put the iPad in airplane mode and then load a viewcontroller with a MKMapView added to it, you get the basic world map, but don't get any data when you zoom in which is fine as I want to disable zooming. Unless what I see is cached data?

Comment: I don't know if there is a special case for the top level map that ensures that the top level is always available... but I can't remember seeing any mention of it in the docs. I'd be hesitant to rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

try this function for get latitude and longitude for address:-(if you use only country name then we get center lat nag long for that country)

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) countryStr {
    NSString *urlAddressStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                           [countryStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *locationStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddressStr]];
    NSArray *items = [locationStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double lat = 0.0;
    double long = 0.0;

    if([items count] >= 4 && [[items objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"])
   {
        lat = [[items objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        long = [[items objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = lat;
    location.longitude = long;

    return location;
}
```

after you get latitude and longitude
1)add use the mapKit Framework

3)set latitude and longitude on region

3) use this function

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this method relies on an internet connection to do the lookup. It did help with setting lat & long within CLLocationCoordinate2D

Answer (score 1):

This method will not work unless you store the data file (sqlite) into the application and query the database as you place the pins into the map. But it will guarantee the map data availability in offline mode.

Basically you can make use of the shape file available
http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

Import it as sqlite file using the .loadshp command described
http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-tutorial-2.3.1.html

Once you have imported the sqlite file, you can just query something like

```
select lon,lat from world_borders where name like 'Zambia';
```

where

```
lon = longitude, 
lat = latitude, 
world_borders = table name
and 'Zambia' = country name.
```

Comment: To save you the trouble, I have imported the file into the sqlite file available 
https://github.com/nhisyam/World-Borders

Comment: Many thanks, this doesn't actually answer my question but its a great help. This does give me a fully country list and the relevant lat/longs which I also needed. :)